# Can I merge translation between 2 sites?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have site 1 and site 2. I've been doing some manually translations at: **admin/config/regional/translate/translate** and also I updated the translation at: **admin/config/regional/translate/update** in both sites.

I'd like to merge the translation betweeen these two sites. Can I do this?

Comment: plz expand details.

Comment: You could find the associated source and target relations in the database (nid and tnid) and change the associations to merge them. If you add more details to your post you may get more constructive responses.